# Transient error. Retry issue when calling GVault Create Hold API

Tags: google-vault-api

We use the GVault Hold API to create holds in GVault on behalf of our customers using the API defined here https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.holds/create, via the Google.Apis.Vault.v1 Nuget package for .NET (version 1.49.0.2171).

We have a specific customer that, when we call VaultService.Matters.Holds.Create.ExecuteAsync (which calls the above HTTP API as I understand), we're consistently getting back 13 for the response status code, and the status message is "Transient error. Retry". No matter how many times we attempt to create or update the hold, however, we get this same response back. The code that wraps the call to the API is wrapped in exponential backoff logic, so we'll retry up to 5 times with progressively longer delays between each retry before finally stopping and logging the error out.

Is it possible that there's something specific with this customer's workspace? Our other customers are not experiencing this issue. Is there any guidance that you can provide for solving this issue?

Thanks in advance!!!

Basic idea of what we're doing

```
hold.Accounts = accounts; // The accounts being added to the hold
return await _vaultService // This is our initialized GoogleVaultClient instance
  .Matters
  .Holds
  .Create(hold, matterId)
  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Does it work if you do it through the web UI? Also, can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Hi Lorena, sorry for the delay in responding; I spent a few days in the ER.  To answer your question, though, yes, it does work when done through the UI. Unfortunately, I don't think I can provide a minimal example; this issue happens only with one of our customers, so I can't replicate it outside their workspace. But effectively, what we're doing is simple.

Comment: I've added sample code to the main post.

Comment: Since Google has made it clear (just got out of a chat with them) that this is the ONLY way to get support for developer concerns, what else do I need to provide on this issue to get help? I have customers waiting. I've posted a code sample of what we're doing; I'm not sure that more is needed, but if there's something specific (other than customer data, which I won't post on StackOverflow), please let me know.